# React-table not displaying the data on new data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-table

I've created a react-table for displaying notifications, and also have it subscribed to an event-source to get real time notifications, but after receiving the data, the table doesn't get refreshed.

[image: Table with data]
In this first screenshot, the data was first retrieved from the db to populate the table.

[image: Empty table]
Then here, after the event-source sent a message, the message is printed to the console but the table is empty.

Below is part of the code to create the table, specifically the useEffect connecting to an event-source.

```js
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
const [tableColumns, setTableColumns] = useState<
  { Header: string; accessor: never }[]
>(new Array<{ Header: string; accessor: never }>());

// connect to event source to get real time data from msg broker
useEffect(() => {
  const eventSource = new EventSource(SseApiUrl);

  eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
    const newData = JSON.parse(event.data).payload;
    console.log(newData);
    const newTableData = tableData;
    newTableData.push(newData as never);
    setTableData(newTableData);
  };

  return () => {
    eventSource.close();
  };
}, [SseApiUrl]);

const data = useMemo(() => tableData, [tableData]);
const columns = useMemo(() => tableColumns, [tableColumns]);

const tableInstance = useTable({ columns, data });
const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = tableInstance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after talking to ChatGPT for a bit, I managed to resolve my issue. The answer given by the other user actually prompted me to ask the right question.

The main issue was in the useEffect for the event-source. I needed to create a new array and in my previous implementation, `const newTableData = TableData` still points to TableData in memory.

The other two smaller issues being, one, my number of columns from the new data were incorrect, two, the data pushed into the table was actually a string instead of JSON object.

Below are the edits I made:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const eventSource = new EventSource(SseApiUrl);

  eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
    const newData = JSON.parse(event.data).payload;
    const newTableData = [...tableData]; // create a new copy of the array
    newTableData.push(JSON.parse(newData) as never); // add the new data to the new copy
    setTableData(newTableData); // set the new copy as the state
  };

  return () => {
    eventSource.close();
  };
}, [SseApiUrl, tableData]);
```